# After the autocomplete is finished

Tags: jquery

I am using this [autocomplete Plugin](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#installation) which works great but the problem is

```
$('#request_song').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: '<%= ajax_path("trackName") %>',
  minChars:1,
  width: 300,
  delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
  deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
  params: { artists: 'Yes' },
});


<div class="field">
  <label for="request_song">Song</label><br />
  <input id="request_song" name="request[song]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
```

This works well but is there a callback or something that will tell me when its complete and someone selected something. I basically want to show a div thats currently hidden on the page or call an action via ajax to get some info.. But how do i know when someone selected soemthing. I was thinking of seeing if the textbox losses focus but I dont know the syntax for that and I was thinking there should be a better way to do that with this plugin or Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE ONSELECT event

```
$('#request_song').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: '<%= ajax_path("trackName") %>',
  minChars:1,
  width: 300,
  delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
  deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
  params: { artists: 'Yes' },
  onselect: function(value, data){
    //DO SOMETHING HERE
  }
});
```